# Захват данных со входа звуковой карты

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио

Как на Python осуществить захват данных со входа звуковой карты: потока с заданными параметрами (частотой дискретизации и разрядности), или одиночных выборок?

Comment: Использовать биндинги к одной из кросс-плафтформенный библиотек? (Вы бы ещё проще спросили "Хочу захватить звук. Как?")

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом, это делается с помощью библиотеки PyAudio. На ютубе есть ролики на эту тему, поищи. Или в документации код посмотри там не плохой рабочий пример выложен. Или вот так -

```
import pyaudio
import wave

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name']) #вывод в консоль всех входов и выходов звуковых устройств по их id


#далее параметры захвата аудио
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2                                # количество каналов в записываемом файле
RATE = 48000                                # значение параметра звука sample-rate
RECORD_TIME = 12                          # длительность захвата в секундах
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"         # имя выходного файла


stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,              # открытие потока с заданными параметрами
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                input_device_index=0,       # номер ID канала, с которого надо записывать звук
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("\n\n Recording..")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_TIME)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("..end recording")


stream.stop_stream()            # остановка потока 
stream.close()                   # закрытие потока 
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')       # создание и открытие файла на запись
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))                # запись сохраненного потока в файл 
wf.close()                                       # закрытие файла
```